# Why did T'Pol act like a human woman with Trip?

Tags: star-trek, tv, star-trek-enterprise

I've found this photo on web which reminds me the scene from *Star Trek: Enterprise*:

[[NSFW] Naked T'Pol from the back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hrNa.jpg)

As I've remembered.. After Trip became jealous of his own clone, she kissed him & then undressed herself.
Showing boobies & her naked body has to do with emotions. Vulcans don't have emotions, so she was unable to think that way to trigger her mate's emotions. But, still she undressed herself in front of Trip to excite him. Why?

Comment: Your premise is flawed. Her mate is human, she knows humans. She's acting completely logical. By the way, sexual attraction doesn't necessarily go hand-in-hand with emotions.

Comment: Vulcans do have emotions; they just suppress them.

Comment: @KeithThompson Emotion suppression was their nature. Without suppression, a Vulcan could go out-of-control what was never seen in T'Pol before that event.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: I wouldn't say it's their *nature*.  It takes a lot of discipline and deliberate effort.

Comment: @bitmask Logically, she could offer this to Archer when he was interested in her before. But, she didn't.

Comment: Clearly she was auditioning for _Vulcans Gone Wild_.

Comment: @Kevin Why have you replaced embedded image with link to image? It was displayed on family TV. What's the problem?

Comment: See [this meta question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1582/3267) on it. I think it's fine for families but I don't think people want the image on their monitor at work.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks... I have improved the clarification of link.

Comment: And unless one is stuck in 8th grade, the appropriate term is "breasts," not "b00bies" I'm just sayin' ;)

Comment: @Slytherincess Hey, I didn't use "boobies" in 8th grade! I don't think I ever did!

Comment: @SovereignInquiry - as a woman I'm glad to hear this!  :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't find it coincidental that this incident occurred in the same year (2154) that T'Pol became addicted to trellium-D after her exposure to it aboard the *Seleya* in the Expanse.  According to the [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/T%27Pol) wiki on T'Pol, her prolonged exposure to the substance permanently damaged her ability to fully control her emotions.

However, in a very Vulcan move, T'Pol commented to Trip that their sexual experience together was merely her "exploration of human sexuality" and had nothing to do with emotions.  I find this, personally, unlikely since this incident occurred right in the middle of T'Pol's trellium-D addiction.

There are many references throughout *Enterprise* of T'Pol experiencing emotional situations--in fact, it seems to me that throughout the series, T'Pol struggles with her emotions more than any Vulcan we've seen prior to this (not helped, of course, by the trellium-D).

Comment: T'Pol also had an emotional experience at a Jazz nightclub years before the Enterprise, and her mother commented that T'Pol has aways been bad a controlling her emotions.  An episode from season 5 was intended to reveal that T'Pol's father was an undercover Romulan, which would've also explained her long interest in emotions

Comment: @Izkata Season 5? I think, _Star Trek: Enterprise_ was 4 seasons long..

Comment: @SachinShekhar Exactly, the series was canceled before anything [planned for Season 5](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Undeveloped_Star_Trek:_Enterprise_episodes#Proposed_fifth_season_episodes) came about

Comment: @Izkata Then, how do you know about mystery of T'Pol's father?

Comment: @SachinShekhar Take a look at the link in my comment...  It would have been a -very- controversial season, including showing the origin of the Borg Queen, and numerous Mirror Universe episodes.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, there are multiple explanations (many of which have been noted) for this.

1. She is aware of human customs, and if she has an interest in Trip she would, logically, be accommodating. Had Trip been another species, she most likely would have acted in accordance with that species.
2. The Trellium-D affected her abilities to control her emotions as well as most Vulcans do.
3. Her emotions were always "closer to the surface" than most other Vulcans. This is referenced multiple times: Being drawn to the "chaotic" jazz music, Her ability to tolerate the company of humans (it was stated in an episode that the previous Vulcan stationed aboard a human starship lasted mere days), and also her mother even directly mentions that her feelings were always closer to the surface.

I'd like to take some exception to "emotions being dangerous" to Vulcans. This is where Trek is rather obscure, and seems to indicate it is not the emotions themselves, but rather the actions that are taken BECAUSE of those emotions that are dangerous. Canon also seems to hint that, though they are definitely suppressing their emotions, Vulcans also use the very notion that they are without emotion to explain away their emotional responses with logic. A prime example of clear emotions in a Vulcan can be seen in the Deep Space Nine episode "Take Me Out to the Holosuite". Solok's emotions can be clearly seen, from the smugness at the beginning of the episode to the frustration at the end when, despite losing, the "Niners" celebrate as though they have won. These can all be explained away with logic, but the emotion is clearly there.

One last note: Though it was stated in Enterprise that Vulcans do not have a predilection for exploration, numerous actions by both Vulcans themselves as well as later Vulcans in starfleet show that CURIOSITY is one of the emotions that appears to be tolerated more than any other.

Comment: Believe curiosity is more of an intellectual trait than an emotional one.  +1 anyway.

Comment: Curiosity is merely a way to make the world complete. Without curiosity why would you be interested in the result of reason? Being without emotion is not to be without drive or motivation. /vulcanLogic

Answer (score 5):

Quite frankly she didn't do her self-control routines properly. That and her addiction to emotion-inducing trellium-D made it impossible to resist Trip's sexy accent. Something about that man heats her plasma, if you know what I mean.

It should be noted that emotions are dangerous for Vulcans, which is why they follow ancient and highly effective routines to suppress them. Vulcans do however, although some would like to deny it, have emotions. In fact they have a knack for passive-aggression and an unusual sense of humor involving showing inferiority.

Note that Star Trek Enterprise wasn't very tidy with canon, I thought the amount of emotions she expressed prior to trillium-D were unacceptable.

Edit: Trillium-D was actually a neurotoxin that only affects Vulcan's self-control. Go figure. Although the effects of exposure wears off there's some chance of permanent damage. To elaborate on the "emotion inducing" stuff a bit.

Comment: “Something about that man heats her plasma, if you know what I mean.” I don’t know what you mean. Plz to explain in detail.

Comment: Well, she wouldn't mind lowering her shields for a good torpedoing.

Comment: It's like when the warp drive got stuck while it was overheating.

Comment: She's rerouting emergency power to 'engineering'.

Comment: She green lights his docking procedures.

Comment: When she said she wanted to be one with him, she didn't mean mind melding.

Comment: Well.. Anyway.. Let's just say she figured out how to make him relax after that mess on earth with his sister and stuff.

Comment: Oh! I see, she’s inviting him to make an incursion into her Neutral Zone.

Comment: She’d like him to launch his probe into her Delphic Expanse.

Comment: He’s manning her helm and taking her to full impulse.

Comment: She’s ordering him to pilot his *Rio Grande* into her Celestial Temple.

Comment: I think I’ve confused myself now.

Comment: Well, if they get busted she can always say she "Tripped"

Answer (score 0):

If you think about Sarek, his explaination is quite logical as to why he married Spock's mother. Being an ambassador, he wanted to learn all about Terrans (humans) even though we later learn he had emotions for her that he kept to himself.

As to why Jolene Blalock complained the whole Trip/T'pol thing was rather misconceived and more to do with lifting ratings. The Trellium-D's explanation as a way to get close to Trip is highly flawed as there was no logical reason for not forming a direct relationship with another species.

Furthermore, consider Season 1 when Flox asks T'Pol about inter-species relationships. She does not rule it out but believes that Humans are not mature enough for it.

If T'Pol wanted a relationship there was nothing to stop her logically especially as she had left the High Command.